# Value of matrix elements between bound and unbound states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, discrete, normalization

How do you assign a numerical value to the matrix element between states of the discrete part $|n\rangle  $and the continuous parts $|\alpha\rangle $of a spectrum of an operator ? The states of the continuous spectrum have no well defined norm so how do you assign a value to a matrix element like
$$
\langle n|\alpha\rangle
$$
where $n$ is the index for the discrete set of states and $\alpha$ is a parameter for the continous states. Is such an expression even defined ? An example could be bound states of an electron in an atom and plane waves for excited unbound states of the electron.

When expressions like this occur, how are they evaluated, or is there a work around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about overlaps between the discrete and continuous states of the same hermitian operator, they will always vanish (as in the bound vs unbound energy eigenstates that you mentioned).

In general though, it does make sense to ask about the overlap between a normalizable state and a non-normalizable one. This is actually something that we do all the time. When we talk about the "position wavefunction" $\psi(x)$ this is actually

$$ \psi(x) = \langle x|\psi \rangle$$

Here, $|x \rangle$ is an eigenstate of the unbounded operator x, beloning to the continous spectrum. Clearly, this quantitiy is well defined, even though the norm $\langle x|x\rangle = \infty$. The difference between this quantity and the overlap between normalizable wavefunctions is that the latter is a set of numbers while the former is a density. (In this sense, the "dimensionality" of $\langle x|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle x_i |\psi \rangle$ for a regularized set of wavefunctions $|x_i\rangle$ is really different)

If you want a more "computational" example consider the overlap of the eigenfunctions of the harmonic oscillator with the eigenfunctions of the momentum operator, i.e plane waves.

$$ \langle k|E_n\rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int dx \,e^{-ikx} \psi_n(x) $$

It is just the fourier transform of the energy eigenstate wavefunction.

The probability that the energy eigenstate has a momentum in the intervall $[k_0,k_0+\Delta k]$ is

$$ P = \int_{k_0}^{k_0+\Delta k} dk \, |\langle k |E_n\rangle|^2$$

This can be verified by considering the finite box model (of lenght L), where the momentum eigenstates $|k_n \rangle$ are normalizable and the momentum is quantized $k_n = \frac{2 \pi n}{L}$:

$$ P = \sum_{k_n} |\langle k_n|\psi \rangle |^2 = \sum_{k_n} |\int dx \frac{e^{-ik_n x}}{\sqrt{L}} \psi(x)|^2$$

and the limit $\sum_{k_n} \rightarrow L \int \frac{dk}{2\pi}$.

Comment: So i do get a transition density in the case of bound/undbounded state overlap and not a simple transition probability as in the case of bound/bound state overlap. And i would always have to integrate this density a second time to obtain an actual transition probability. Is this correct ?  Another point that is still unclear to me is how do you fix the fourier convention ? Am i not free to distribute a factor of 2 $\pi$ between fourier transform pairs ? Shouldn't there be only one way to do it, fixed by physical reasons ?

Comment: Yes you get an amplitude density, the absolute square of this gives a probability density, and by integrating across a certain range of k or E you get the probability. Regarding the fourier convention, this is connected to the density business. You can always regard the continous model as a limit of discrete states. For example plane waves that you put into a finite box. The wavefunctions $|k_n \rangle$ are then normalizable and you have a discrete set of them. Sums over k are transformed into an integral according to $\sum_{k_n} \rightarrow V \int \frac{dk}{2\pi}$.

Comment: This is also where the factor of $2 \pi$ comes from, I was a bit sloppy there in the original answer.